# Aggregate EC2 costs with key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cost-management

Unfortunately, in my org there is not a good tag enforcement. Is it possible to group the ec2 costs by key pair used using boto3 or some other way? I don't see any methods here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html

*I was able to do it with tag.*

Answer (score 1):

A keypair is used to authenticate to the operating system. AWS has no involvement in this login process. Therefore, it cannot **link activity to keypairs**. (That is, it doesn't know *who* is logging in each time.)

However, instances do have a `KeyName` attribute that identifies which Keypair was used when the instance was launched. Users could still login under a different username if that user has been created on the instance.

While the `KeyName` attribute is associated with an instance, it cannot be used to group costs. You could, however, **copy the KeyName to a Tag**, which could then be used for grouping in billing reports.